# Google Cloud SQL Mysql group replication

Tags: mysql, replication, google-cloud-sql

On the Google platform using Cloud SQL MySQL version 5.7, is it possible to setup Group Replication as defined in the MySQL documentation chapter 18 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication.html)?

I want to be able to setup 3 masters in a group. Each master would have at least 1 read only slave. The masters would be behind a load balancer for writing. The slaves would be behind a load balancer for reading.

Comment: JL-HN if you want to correct my spelling, that is fine. But do not change the question. I am not currently using Google Cloud Sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not supported on Cloud SQL.

Comment: Vadim, is there a particular reason it is not supported?

Comment: It's not something that a lot of customers have asked for. Things could of course change in the future, but ultimately the team has finite time and has to choose which features to focus on.